# TestNG IReporter , how to call generateReport method.

Tags: java, testng

From one of the example(s) I found a method generateReport(List xml, List suites, String outdir). 
From where can i call this method/how to get the parameter values to call this method.

Comment: Question is incomplete.. Are u using jasperReport to generate report or what ? give more details

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement the IReporter interface, if you want to generate a custom report for your testng runs.
Please refer to testng documentation  @
[Logging Reporters](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-reporters)

You do not need to call it, TestNG would be invoking it..

Comment: Implemented an instance of IReporter and the generateReport(List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory). Added respective <parameter><name>reporter</name><value>customreport.MyReport</value></parameter> in pom.xml. Where should i configure the value for "outputDirectory" incase if it is invoking by TestNG automatically.

Comment: You can put this in your configuration section ..<reportsDirectory>whateverpath</reportsDirectory>.  I think you will have to make the property as listener and not reporter.  
What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to execute the code written in generateReport method. I configured in pom  as mentioned. This method been implemnted using IReporter interface. Once the execution completes TestNG is not calling this method automatically. I am not able to found what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

See the Maven Surefire documentation for properly attaching a custom listener or reporter. The bottom of the linked page explains how to configure a custom reporter like the one you created.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html

Answer (score -1):

```
This method can invoke in your custom listener class 

 public class MyReportListener extends MyReporterListenerAdapter {
    // do your stuff............................
    //...........................

        @Override
            public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xml, List<ISuite> suites,
                    String outdir) {
        // do your stuff
        }
       } 



    public class MyReporterListenerAdapter implements IReporter {

        @Override
        public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> arg0, List<ISuite> arg1,
                String arg2) {
            /**
             *  TODO Auto-generated method stub
             */

        }

    }

I think this helps you
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a custom listener class file: "Run_Listen.java" present within a package named "com.qa.api.utils". Place the following snippet in maven.

```
<properties>
    <property>
        <name>listener</name>`
            <value>com.qa.api.utils.Run_Listen</value>`
    </property>
</properties>
```